# Have Subdomain point to a different azure address

Tags: azure-web-app-service, google-domain-api

I'm trying to setup my google domains to where "blah.net" points to my app in azure sites, but I want "dev.blah.net" to point to a different app on azure (My dev instance).

Anyone know how to setup this up?  I tried doing subdomain forwarding but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to setup my google domains to where "blah.net" points to my app in azure sites, but I want "dev.blah.net" to point to a different app on azure

You could use A record for your root domain(blah.net) and CName record for your sub domain(dev.blah.net). Steps below are for your reference.

1. Get  production web app IP address, pre-configured domain and dev web app pre-configured domains from Azure Portal.

[image]

2. Configuration A record, CName record and TXT record as following in Google domain management tool.

[image]

3. Add hostname for your product and dev app on Azure portal.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I tried creating A records and txt records for it, and then I even tried creating a cname record for it but I did not put dev in as the host. Your pictures helped me fix what I had done wrong. I would love to give you two upvotes for how perfect your description was with pictures!